# Класс ChildClass наследует класс ParentClass, при этом возникает ряд ошибок

Tags: java

```
package ext;

class ParentClass {
     void parent() {
         System.out.println("Суперкласс");
     }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    void child() {
        System.out.println("Подкласс");
    }
}
```

Появляются ошибки:

> ```
>   ChildClass:
>     C:\программы\ext\ChildClass.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
>     class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
>                              ^
>       symbol: class ParentClass
>     1 error
> ```

```
class Main {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChildClass c = new ChildClass();     
        ParentClass p = new ParentClass();   
        c.parent();      
        c.child();   
        p.parent();     
    } 
}
```

Ошибки Main:

> ```
> C:\программы\ext\Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
>      ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
>      ^
>   symbol:   class ChildClass
>   location: class Main
> C:\программы\ext\Main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
>      ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
>                         ^
>   symbol:   class ChildClass
>   location: class Main
> C:\программы\ext\Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
>      ParentClass p = new ParentClass();
>      ^
>   symbol:   class ParentClass
>   location: class Main
> C:\программы\ext\Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
>      ParentClass p = new ParentClass();
>                          ^
>   symbol:   class ParentClass
>   location: class Main
> 4 errors
> ```

Comment: ты чего-то недоговариваешь https://ideone.com/TWlRnO

Comment: Тут по моему проблема в кодировке..

Comment: у меня такие ошибки возникают в блокноте , если сохраняю в UTF-8.Нужно в ANSI.

Comment: А где `public class` ? Ошибка из-за того, что нет публичного главного класса.

Answer (score 0):

C:\программы... - вот это корень зла. Измените имя каталога, в котором храните свой код, там не стоит использовать русский алфавит. Все только на латыни плюс цифры. Причем не просто сама папка с кодом, а весь путь , т.е. все вложенные папки, начиная с самого диска, стоит именовать только латинскими буквами и цифрами

Comment: Java не испытывает с этим никаких проблем, это не Python.